# Run Docker Image from Tekton Task

Tags: docker, tekton

Is it possible to run a docker image from a Tekton task? A majority of examples I have seen have to do with building and deploying Docker Images with Tekton, but nothing on how to run an already built image.

I am using a cron job to trigger a Tekton EventListener which then runs a Taskrun. I want the task to run a docker image hosted on a private docker repo. The Taskrun refers to this Task.

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1alpha1
kind: Task
metadata:
  name: update-ip
spec:
  steps:
    - name: update-ip
      image: [<private-docker-repo>]
      command: ["docker"]
      args: ["run", <private-docker-repo/path-to-image>]
```

Here is an example of common tutorials i see

https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/build-and-deploy-a-docker-image-on-kubernetes-using-tekton-pipelines/

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The "task" of each Tekton task is to run a container (image). So, it will be sufficient to state your container image, and that's it.

Your example should look like

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1alpha1
kind: Task
metadata:
  name: update-ip
spec:
  steps:
    - name: update-ip
      image: <private-docker-repo/path-to-image/image-name:image-tag>
```

`command` and `args` are optional, if you want to execute something else than the ENTRYPOINT and/or CMD, that is defined by your container image.
For even more flexibility, you can alternatively state a `script`, which allows to execute several commands within your container, like a shell script.

*Hints*:

- For your private registry, remember to add a pull secret to the service account (if your repo has restricted access).
- In newer versions of Tekton, the apiVersion changed to `tekton.dev/v1beta1`.

Answer (score 0):

Your are looking for **DinD** ( Docker In Docker) feature with tekton:

This is a [complete example](https://github.com/tektoncd/pipeline/blob/main/examples/v1/taskruns/dind-sidecar.yaml), and it should answer your need:

focus on the [sidecar section (L42 -> L66)](https://github.com/tektoncd/pipeline/blob/main/examples/v1/taskruns/dind-sidecar.yaml#L42-L66) where the dind container is added.

Comment: It gives a 404 error for the links provided

Comment: I checked the source code & i found they renamed folder v1alpah1 to v1. Links updated!